# Find a linear map $T:R^3\to R^3$ where $R(T)=\{x+y+z=0\}, N(T)=span(\{0,0,1\})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linear map $T:R^3\to R^3$ where $R(T)=\{x+y+z=0\}, N(T)=span(\{0,0,1\})$.

I know that $R(T)=span(\{(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1)\})$ and that I "have" to use the standard basis for $R^3$, of which I know the image of one.

How can I find $T(0,1,0), T(0,0,1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $N(T)$ denotes the kernel then $$ T=\begin{bmatrix} -1&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&1&0 \end{bmatrix} $$ does the job.

Comment: Did you simply let $T(0,1,0)=(-1,1,0), T(0,0,1)=(-1,0,1)$? And how would one write out the formal equation for T?

Comment: $T(0,0,1) = (0,0,0) $ by definition. $T(1,0,0) $ and $T(0,1,0)$ is in $span\{(-1,1,0),(-1,01)}$ so any T that sends $e_1$ and $e_2$ into some linear combination of the vectors $(-1,1,0),(-1,0,1)$ does the job. Note that I wrote T in the form that it acts on culomn vectors from the left.